# how to run a robot test command in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I want to run a robot test command manually inside jenkins running in Linux OS centos.
The location of the Test command is inside the /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tests_commands/setlogin/

I created a new freestyle job and used this script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('intialize') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "PATH= ${PATH}"'
                }
            }
        stage('Test the Logon') {
            steps { 
                  sh 'python3 -m robot Tests_commands/setlogin/LogonTest.robot'
                }
            }                   
        }
}
```

And Im getting this error :

```
+ pipeline '{'
/tmp/jenkins3118064166689315550.sh: line 2: pipeline: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Robot results publisher started...
-Parsing output xml:
Failed!
```

Can i ask advice to give some idea how i will have a success run by manually running the robot test command.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you say you have created a freestyle job, but it seems you are using pipeline syntax. If you are using execute shell step in freestyle job than just symply use "python3 -m robot Tests_commands/setlogin/LogonTest.robot". That is probobaly why you see the "pipeline: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

In freestyle job, you cannot run pipeline groovy syntax. You need to use pipeline in order to use groovy.